# Main page content block doesn't move

Tags: blocks, layout-builder

I'm currently building a Drupal 9 site.
I've built some custom blocks, which I display on a specific 'basic page'.
I want the 'Main Page Content' block to be above my custom blocks. So I moved the 'Main Page Content' block upwards. For some reason it didn't update, and my custom blocks are still on top.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: First, always clear the cache.  Next: Where are the custom blocks still on top?  In the layout builder UI?  Or are they on bottom in layout builder but on top in the actual page?

Comment: @PatrickKenny I already clear cache with every change. In the layout builder the main page content is on top. And on the actual page the custom content is on top.

Comment: What does the page source look like?  Check for the layout builder classes in the raw HTML, and consider updating your question here to show the actual markup that Drupal is outputting.

Comment: @PatrickKenny I managed to fix it. I only had main page content shown on a couple of specific pages. Added the needed page to it, and it directly got placed on the right direction. Altough that page wasn't in the list of pages before, I'm guessing that whenever 'Main page content' is enabled, that it automatically gets placed under all other blocks

Comment: If you solved the issue, please answer your own question instead of posting it in a comment.  That way you can later mark the question solved, so it won't show up as unanswered in the search results.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue. I only had main page content shown on a couple of specific pages. Added the needed page to it, and it directly got placed on the right direction. Although that page wasn't in the list of pages before, I'm guessing that whenever 'Main page content' is enabled, that it automatically gets placed under all other blocks